# How do I get the url of my post in react and node application as a string?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So, I am using react-share and I am trying to enable users to share posts. React share said that I need to place the page url as a string. But I used this code to fetch the url of the post individually:

```
 const url = window.location.href;
```

But I can't use the url variable in the react-share since it is requesting a string in this format:

```
return (
 <div>
 <FacebookShareButton url="string-url">
 <FacebookIcon lightingColor="white" round={true}>

 </FacebookIcon>
```

)
   }

How do I get each post's url as a string in my react application?

Answer (score 0):

Since `url` is already a string, you can pass it as a prop to the `FacebookShareButton` component as follows.

```
return (
 <div>
 <FacebookShareButton url={url}>
 <FacebookIcon lightingColor="white" round={true}>

 </FacebookIcon>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Like I said, it didnt work. It must be passed as a string. I tried this method but didnt work

Comment: got the point...let me check it again